# RandomAccessFile медленнее BufferedReader?

Tags: java, файлы

Здравствуйте, есть файл, в нем хранятся английские слова на 'a' и их перевод сразу на другой сроке...
Приходиться что бы узнать перевод слова который находиться в средине или конце проходить с самого начала через BufferedReader. Я создал новый файл, который говорит что 'aa' находиться с такого символа и столько то строк. Также для 'ab' 'ac' ... 'az' 
Далее через RandomAccessFile я переходу на нужный символ и знаю что слово потенциально должно находиться на определенном промежутке.

Вопрос: почему в случае когда я использую BufferedReader он в определенных случаях работает до 10 раз быстрее, чем RandomAccessFile

Comment: В случае с axe или axes  RandomAccessFile находит перевод за 4-6 милисекунд..а BufferedReader за 30+

Comment: Т.е. если есть 500 слов ...на ax+" " то первые слова RandomAccessFile находит оочень быстро...но если слово где то в средине...то уже лучше BufferedReader с самого начала документа проходить –

Comment: 4-6 миллисекунд против 30 - слишком маленькие времена чтобы делать выводы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BufferedReader выигрывает за счет уменьшения количества обращений к системе, RandomAccessFile - предназначен для чтения и записи файла одновременно, т.е. не заточен на быстрое чтение, единственное за счет чего он теоретически может выигрывать это возможность пропустить ненужную информацию, т.е. прыгнуть сразу в нужное смещение с помощью методов `seek` или `skipBytes`, в остальном же даже методы чтения в массив в итоге сводятся к побайтовому чтению (см исходники).
если производительность критична, я бы попробовал новый вариант RandomAccessFile - `Files.newByteChannel()` или `FileChannel.open()`